# Ascending integer pyramid

Tags: code-golf

Output either the text below, or a list of lists of integers (more details below).

```
 0
10  1
20 11  2
30 21 12  3
40 31 22 13  4
50 41 32 23 14  5
60 51 42 33 24 15  6
70 61 52 43 34 25 16  7
80 71 62 53 44 35 26 17  8
90 81 72 63 54 45 36 27 18  9
91 82 73 64 55 46 37 28 19
92 83 74 65 56 47 38 29
93 84 75 66 57 48 39
94 85 76 67 58 49
95 86 77 68 59
96 87 78 69
97 88 79
98 89
99
```

### Rules

- If you wish, you may "one index" and replace each `n` with `n+1`. In this case the output will contain the numbers 1 to 100 inclusive.

#### If output is text

- The single digits are right aligned in each column in the text provided, but it is fine if you wish to left align. Additionally, alignment is not required to be consistent between columns.
- Leading/trailing whitespace is permitted. Trailing spaces on each line are also permitted.
- Returning a list of lines is acceptable.

#### If output is numerical

- Output can be a list of lists of integers (or 2D array): `[[1], [11, 2], [21...`
- Floats are fine.
- If it is not possible to have nonrectangular array in the language used, then the elements in the array that aren't within the triangle can take any value and will be ignored.

If you prefer another format, feel free to ask.

Shortest code wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16286/75553)

Comment: Since leading/trailing white-space is permitted in the textual output, are leading/trailing empty lists permitted in the list output?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sure

Comment: i cant edit it in, but this should have the kolmogorov complexity tag (not sure i spelled that right...)

Comment: @BrianH. According to others, since there isn't really a single constant that is meant to be produced, the KC tag doesn't apply here

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13 12 10</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-4 thanks to Dennis, yes FOUR! (use of group indices and Cartesian product)

```
⁵pḅ1ĠU
```

Uses 1-indexing and the list option for output.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//4oG1cOG4hTHEoFX/wqLFkuG5mP8)** (The footer formats the output in Python representation)
...or see a [0-indexed, formatted version](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49aChztaDY8sCP1/aNGjhpnu/wE).

#### How?

```
⁵pḅ1ĠU - Main link: no arguments
⁵      - literal 10
 p     - Cartesian product (with the leading constant of 10 and implicit ranges)
       -       = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],...,[10,8],[10,9],[10,10]]
  ḅ1   - to base one (proxy for sum each without the monad)
       -       = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,4,...,18,19,20]
    Ġ  - group indices by value
       -       = [[1],[2,11],[3,12,21],...,[90,99],[100]]
     U - upend = [[1],[11,2],[21,12,3],...,[99,90],[100]]
```

Comment: Nice. I had [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41btw/sS3I4sCP1/aJH7fwA)

Comment: What in the world does `Ġ` even do?!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn it groups the indices of an array by their corresponding value. So `[5,7,5,9]Ġ` would return `[[1,3],[2],[4]]`.  This is because indices `[1,3]` correspond to value `5` in the original array, `[2]` to `7` and `[4]` to `9`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
k=1
exec"print range(k,0,-9)[:101-k];k+=10-k/91*9;"*19
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9vWkCu1IjVZqaAoM69EoSgxLz1VI1vHQEfXUjPaytDAUDc71jpb29bQQDdb39JQy9JaScvQ8v9/AA)

(1-indexed, because `range(k,0,-9)` is shorter than `range(k,-1,-9)`.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>29</s> 20 bytes

```
Ｅ¹⁹⪫Ｉ⮌Φ¹⁰⁰⁼ι⁺÷λχ﹪λχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdJCgJBDEDRq4ReRYhQtRSXDqDQ0HiD0B0wEKq0putHBf/m8dcnlzWzuS9FU8OZXxgPBPesCU9cGz5kSKmCV7UmBWMIBJd3Z6uoBIv1irfUzjp0EzSCGHYEc9665f/@Iphg@np09/2wDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Note: trailing space. Explanation:

```
 ¹⁹                     Literal 19
Ｅ                       Map over implicit range
       ¹⁰⁰              Literal 100
      Φ                 Filter over implicit range
              λ  λ      Inner index
               χ  χ     Predefined variable 10
                ﹪       Modulo
             ÷          Integer divide
            ⁺           Sum
           ι            Outer index
          ⁼             Equals
     ⮌                  Reverse
    Ｉ                   Cast to string
   ⪫                    Join with spaces
                        Implicitly print each string on its own line
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes

0-based. Returns a string.

```javascript
f=(k=n=0)=>k>98?k:k+((k-=9)%10>0?' '+f(k):`
`+f(n+=n>89||10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBDkAwEADAu1e4SHfTkLqpZOsrFVRY2YqKk7@X22T28RnTdG3nXUucl5wDAZOQQXLsbDdwzxqAa7JYtcaZQZVKB2DsfeF/iCZxnX3f1iDmKUqKx9IccYUAf3w)

#### How?

We start with **k = n = 0** and stop when **k = 99**. We subtract **9** from **k** at each iteration.

End of rows are detected with `k % 10 <= 0`. This condition is fulfilled if:

- **k** is negative (upper part of the pyramid) because the sign of the modulo in JS is that of the dividend.

  ```
   0 (-9)
  10  1 (-8)
  20 11  2 (-7)
  ```
- *or* **k % 10 == 0** (lower part of the pyramid)

  ```
  90 81 72 63 54 45 36 27 18  9 (0)
  91 82 73 64 55 46 37 28 19 (10)
  92 83 74 65 56 47 38 29 (20)
  ```

At the beginning of the next row, we add either **1** or **10** to **n** and restart from there.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
r=range
for a in r(0,90,10)+r(90,100):print r(a,a/10+a%10*10-1,-9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8i2KDEvPZUrLb9IIVEhM0@hSMNAx9JAx9BAU7tIA8ww0LQqKMrMKwFKJeok6hsaaCeqGhpoGRroGuroWmr@/w8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
,.<@|./.i.,~10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pflFiuYGulYKAAwrp6Cs5BPm7/dfRsHGr09PUy9XTqDA3@a3KlJmfkKyjpARX/BwA)

### Note:

This solution uses boxed output - I'm not sure if it's allowed (I hope it is, because lists of integers are also allowed)

### Alternative:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
|./.i.,~10
```

In this solution the numbers outside the triangular area are displayed as `0`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pflFiuYGulYKAAwrp6Cs5BPm7/a/T09TL1dOoMDf5rcqUmZ@QrKOkBFf4HAA)

### Explanation:

`i.,~10` creates a matrix 10x10 of the numbers 0..99 `,~10` is short for `10 10`

```
   i.,~10
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

`/.` finds the oblique diagonals (antidiagonals) of the matrix

```
   ]/.i.,~10
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2 11 20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 3 12 21 30  0  0  0  0  0  0
 4 13 22 31 40  0  0  0  0  0
 5 14 23 32 41 50  0  0  0  0
 6 15 24 33 42 51 60  0  0  0
 7 16 25 34 43 52 61 70  0  0
 8 17 26 35 44 53 62 71 80  0
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
19 28 37 46 55 64 73 82 91  0
29 38 47 56 65 74 83 92  0  0
39 48 57 66 75 84 93  0  0  0
49 58 67 76 85 94  0  0  0  0
59 68 77 86 95  0  0  0  0  0
69 78 87 96  0  0  0  0  0  0
79 88 97  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
89 98  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
99  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Using `]` (same) pads all lines with `0`s. Each line is reversed. In order to get rid of the zeroes I box the lines `<` after they are reversed `|.`

```
   <@|./.i.,~10
┌─┬────┬───────┬──────────┬─────────────┬────────────────┬
│0│10 1│20 11 2│30 21 12 3│40 31 22 13 4│50 41 32 23 14 5│. . .
└─┴────┴───────┴──────────┴─────────────┴────────────────┴
```

Boxing makes the list of lists to be flatten. I finally ravel `,.` the list so that the lines are ordered in a column.

```
  ,.<@|./.i.,~10
┌────────────────────────────┐
│0                           │
├────────────────────────────┤
│10 1                        │
├────────────────────────────┤
│20 11 2                     │
├────────────────────────────┤
│30 21 12 3                  │
├────────────────────────────┤
│40 31 22 13 4               │
├────────────────────────────┤
│50 41 32 23 14 5            │
├────────────────────────────┤
│60 51 42 33 24 15 6         │
├────────────────────────────┤
│70 61 52 43 34 25 16 7      │
├────────────────────────────┤
│80 71 62 53 44 35 26 17 8   │
├────────────────────────────┤
│90 81 72 63 54 45 36 27 18 9│
├────────────────────────────┤
│91 82 73 64 55 46 37 28 19  │
├────────────────────────────┤
│92 83 74 65 56 47 38 29     │
├────────────────────────────┤
│93 84 75 66 57 48 39        │
├────────────────────────────┤
│94 85 76 67 58 49           │
├────────────────────────────┤
│95 86 77 68 59              │
├────────────────────────────┤
│96 87 78 69                 │
├────────────────────────────┤
│97 88 79                    │
├────────────────────────────┤
│98 89                       │
├────────────────────────────┤
│99                          │
└────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 66

```bash
eval a={{9..1},}\;b={9..0}';c[a+b]+=$a$b\ '
printf %s\\n "${c[@]}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUch0ba62lJPz7BWpzbGOskWxDaoVbdOjk7UTorVtlVJVEmKUVDnKijKzCtJU1AtjonJU1BSqU6OdoitVfr/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>137 86 73</s> 69 bytes

```r
for(u in 0:18)cat("if"(u>9,seq(81+u,10*u-81,-9),seq(10*u,u,-9)),"\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SKNUITNPwcDK0EIzObFEQykzTUmj1M5Spzi1UMPCULtUx9BAq1TXwlBH11ITLAji65SCuJo6SjF5Spr//wMA)

Previous golfed version, %100 credits to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).

```r
S=sapply
c(S(1:10,function(u)1:u-1+10*(u-1:u)),S(9:1,function(y)1:y+9-y+10*(y:1+9-y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9i2OLGgIKeSK1kjWMPQytBAJ600L7kkMz9Po1TT0KpU11Db0EBLA0hblWpq6gRrWFoZIpRUApVUalvqVoIVVVoZgtiampr//wMA)

Below my first attempt at Codegolf keeping it just for the record.

```r
x<-c(1:10)
z<- c(9:1)
c(sapply(x,function(u) seq_len(u)-1+10*(u-seq_len(u))),sapply(z,function(y) seq_len(y)+9-y+10*rev(seq_len(y)+9-y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctNCoAgEEDhfadoOVMNOEuju0SIQSBmP0Z6eUsIpN3jwbendA@kgHsWWMWBagWyZ6wUHJNzJsDdzd6qc1kteKwPvY1G5yRuWTTgqSzE7kOxoFBQwFZSyGzXF/zvi1N6AA)

Comment: Nice answer! Like you say, you can remove quite a few bytes; I've managed to find an [86 byte solution](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9i2OLGgIKeSK1kjWMPQytBAJ600L7kkMz9Po1TT0KpU11Db0EBLA0hblWpq6gRrWFoZIpRUApVUalvqVoIVVVoZgtiampr//wMA) by removing some unnecessary white-space, and replacing `seq_len` with `1:` in most places; I also used `y:1` instead of `rev`.

Comment: @Giuseppe many thanks for the improved answer - it shows that I haven't coded in years.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
V19fqssM`TN_U100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8zQMq2wuNg3IcQvPtTQwOD/fwA)

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8zQMq2wOCvE2i8@1NDA4P9/AA).

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 24 bytes

```
0D9FlF{a+|lD|9F~lF{P|D|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/38DF0i3HrTpRuybHpcbSrQ7IDqhxqbH@/x8A)

The output looks like this:

```
[0]
[10 1]
[20 11 2]
[30 21 12 3]
[40 31 22 13 4]
[50 41 32 23 14 5]
[60 51 42 33 24 15 6]
[70 61 52 43 34 25 16 7]
[80 71 62 53 44 35 26 17 8]
[90 81 72 63 54 45 36 27 18 9]
[91 82 73 64 55 46 37 28 19]
[92 83 74 65 56 47 38 29]
[93 84 75 66 57 48 39]
[94 85 76 67 58 49]
[95 86 77 68 59]
[96 87 78 69]
[97 88 79]
[98 89]
[99]
```

#### How it works

```
0D9FlF{a+|lD|9F~lF{P|D|;

0D                       Push 0 and print stack
  9F        |            Repeat 9 times...
    lF{a+|                 Add 10 to all numbers on the stack
          l                Push stack length (the last one-digit number)
           D               Print stack
             9F       |  Repeat 9 times...
               ~           Discard the top
                lF{P|      Increment all numbers on the stack
                     D     Print stack
                       ; Halt
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```r
split(y<-rev(order(x<-outer(0:9,0:9,"+"))),x[y])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ggJ7NEo9JGtyi1TCO/KCW1SKPCRje/tATIMLCy1AFhJW0lTU1NnYroyljN//8B)

1-indexed. Follows the same logic as Jonathan Allan's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163515/78274), so make sure to upvote him.

As a bonus, here is also an implementation of standard looping approach (0-indexed). Here, I at least tried to make the output prettier (thus, didn't even save bytes for `print` instead of `cat(...,"\n")` to get rid of annoying `[1]`s in the console.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>66</s> 59 bytes

```r
for(i in c(0:8*10,90:99))cat(seq(i,i/10+i%%10*10-1,-9),"
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPIVnDwMpCy9BAx9LAytJSUzM5sUSjOLVQI1MnU9/QQDtTVdXQACita6ija6mpo8SlpPn/PwA)

Edit: -2 and -7 both thanks to Giuseppe.

Comment: I managed to golf down the second one to [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPIVnDwMpCy9BAx9LAytJSUzM5sUSjOLVQI1MnU9/QQDtTVdXQACita6ija6mpo8SlpPn/PwA) and the first to [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ggJ7NEo9JGtyi1TCO/KCW1SKPCRje/tATIMLCy1AFhJW0lTU1NnYroyljN//8B)

Comment: @KirillL.It's always realy elegant to use outer. plus in this case it's shorter!

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>67</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```matlab
for i=0:8disp(10*i:-9:0)end,for i=0:9disp(90+i:-9:11*i+(i<1))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Lb9IIdPWwMoiJbO4QMPQQCvTStfSykAzNS9FByZnCZazNNAGyxkaamVqa2TaGGqCFP3/DwA)

Those missing semicolons hurt my eyes!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
TLûvTLD>T*«NèyGD9+})R,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/xOfw7rIQHxe7EK1Dq/0Or6h0d7HUrtUM0vn/HwA)

---

Super Naive Approach: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/xMfl8KL//wE) may be a better solution but I can't figure out how to get from A to B.

Comment: Is there a "sort a based on values of b" command?

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 77 bytes

```powershell
(0..90|?{!($_%10)})+91..99|%{"$(for($i=$_;$i-gt$_/10+$_%10*10-1;$i-=9){$i})"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoAgEADQsyQjOEU1s5SQjuLKShAMC1qYZ7fP9vH2eLl0bC6EWhUNg6Z7zo0CK5mwYKf5NX3LLEAtMSnwBuwEvl9PsCNT98@WqedPjcYMvqAotT4)

Outputs as ASCII-art with the single-digits left-aligned. Exploits the fact that stringifying an array inserts spaces between elements by default.

Very similar to Rod's Python answer, apparently, but developed independently.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 69 bytes

```
f=(i=e=[])=>e[i<19&&(e[+i]=[]),i/10+i%10|0].unshift(+i)*i++-99?f(i):e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBDsIgEAXQ09jMOLbCEiP2IIRFUwf9poFGalfeHeNbvte0T3V@Y936XO7aWvIErz5E9jcNuFrXdaRBEP93wtkawcGar4nDJ9cn0kYCPkKkd25MBL5om0uuZdFhKQ9KxNx@)

## JavaScript REPL, 77 bytes

```
[...Array(100)].map((_,i)=>e[i<19&&(e[i]=[]),i/10+i%10|0].unshift(i),e=[])&&e
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```perl6
{map {[R,] grep :k,$_,(^10 X+ ^10)},^19}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjexQKE6OkgnViG9KLVAwSpbRyVeRyPO0EAhQlsBSGnW6sQZWtb@L06sVEjT0LT@DwA)

-3 bytes thanks to Brad Gilbert b2gills.

Comment: `[R,] LIST` is shorter than `reverse LIST`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 62 bytes

```perl
$,=$";say@,=map$_+=10,@,,$_ for-9..0;say map++$_,@,while pop@,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZFybo4sdJBxzY3sUAlXtvW0EDHQUdHJV4hLb9I11JPzwAkrQCU1NZWiQdKlWdk5qQqFOQXOOj8//8vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBAA)

1-indexed to save a couple bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>105, 95</strike> 91 bytes

```
v: make vector! 0
loop 10[alter v + 10 length? v print v]loop 9[alter v last v print 1 + v]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxDoAgDAB3X1FnFxh18Q@uhIFIo8YKBJt@vxIHxsvdVYy6YXReZYEn3AiCO@c6ghko5wLWuECMFQSmBkCYDj7XhqVeiUH8n829ovByt7ZN4lU/)

### Explanation:

```
v: make vector!   0                           ; start with a vector with one element: -10
loop 10[alter v + 10 length? v print v]       ; Ten times print the vector after adding 10
                                              ; to its elements and appending the length   
loop 9[alter v last v print 1 + v]            ; Nine times print the vector after adding 1 
                                              ; to its elements and removing the last one
                                              ; `alter` appends the item if it's not
                                              ; in the list, otherwise removes it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```ruby
0.step(180,10){|x|p x.step(0,-9).select{|y|y<100&&y>x-90}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/30CvuCS1QMPQwkDH0ECzuqaipkChAiJmoKNrqalXnJqTmlxSXVNZU2ljaGCgplZpV6FraVBb@/8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), 112 bytes

Not that optimal, but I wanted to try a different approach.

```javascript
[...Array(19)].map((x,y)=>y>9?81+y:y?y+'0':y).map(x=>(f=(n,a=[n])=>!n|a[n+='']|n[1]>8?a:f(n-=9,a.concat(n)))(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoMwEEX3PUW7ygxqqDsVEunGS4SAg9VisRNRKQl491RauvuP9/hPetPaLeO8ZezufWxUNFLK27JQgLxEK180A/g0oNJBl3WRJ6EKdUjEVVQBv9orDYMCTkkZtkd44Z0MJ0oIu7PJrS5qqgbgTJUpyc5xRxswIoJHjAevburl5B7Q/A@9fLqR23OLv3FqMX4A)

Old Solution:

```javascript
[...Array(19)].map((x,y)=>y>9?y-9+'9':y).map((x,y)=>(f=(n,a=[n])=>a[n/10]|!n?a.reverse():a.push(n+=9)&&f(n,a))(x*1).slice(y-19))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BDoIwEAXvfoVeYFdglWNJCvHCTxASGqwKwZa0StrEf6@oF2/zMnmZUSzC9maYH5nSZxlqHhoiOhkjPOQMW7qLGcClHnnpS1b5jCUxiwuP/wYuHFQqeKPadYlGHfJj@9qpSpCRizRWAhaC5qe9gUo4wyi6fA6I4PY5kp2GXoLP1iKGXiurJ0mTvkL9rTheOhr1oLpthz/YdBje)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
тL<ΣTLãOsè}TLû£í
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//YpOPzbnFIT6HF/sXH15RC2TsPrT48Nr//wE)

**Explanation**

```
тL<Σ      }       # sort the values in [0 ... 99] by
        sè        # the value at that index in
       O          # the sum of
      ã           # the cartesian product of
    TL            # the range [1 ... 10]
              £   # split the result into pieces of sizes
           TLû    # [1,2,...,9,10,9,...2,1]
               í  # and reverse each
```